# Extracting all second column values from a ndarray for a given first column value

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy ndarray where first column is user id and second column is some product id. What would be the fastest way to get all product ids for a given user id?

I've been going through the numpy doc and this handbook (https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.02-the-basics-of-numpy-arrays.html) as well but I had no luck.

Say we have this array:

```
test = [[0, 1], [0, 20], [0, 30], [1, 11], [1, 23], [1, 45]]
```

My goal is to get a function like this:

```
get_product_ids(0)

>> [1, 20, 30]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved in such a simple way

```
test = np.array(test)

def get_product_id(ind):
    mask = test[:, 0] == ind
    return test[:, 1][mask]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_product_ids(user_id, user_products):
    products = []

    # In one line using list comprehension
    products.extend([sub_list[1] for sub_list in user_products if sub_list[0] == user_id])

    # if above code is too complicated, used the below three lines instead
    # for sub_list in user_products:
    #    if sub_list[0] == user_id:
    #        products.append(sub_list[1])

    return products

user_products = [[0,1],[0,20],[0,30],[1,11],[1,23],[1,45]]
get_product_ids(0, user_products)
```

Give above a try. I have provided two ways of doing the same thing. Use whichever you prefer.

The complexity is somewhere near O(n) which should be fine and fast enough.

If you are going to use this function a lot of times, I would suggest writing another function that would return a dictionary with user_id as the keys and product_ids as values. That would make the overall operation really efficient than iterating over the full list every time.

With your sample input that dictionary would look something like below:

```
{ 0: [1,20,30], 1: [11,23,45] }
```